# Tracking What We Eat?

Tags: nutrition, diet, diet-tools

My wife and I have both recently been discussing how we can eat healthier. We've been planning menus involving lots of fruit and vegetables, complex carbohydrates, low sugars, good fats, etc. However, we still don't have an overall picture of our nutrition content throughout the day.

While we have been tracking what we eat through a Google Docs spreadsheet, can anybody provide a recommendation for a way (I'm thinking a website) to easily track what we eat and what kind of nutrition we are getting. An excellent feature of the site would be one that "knows" food products. So, if I type in, "Raisin Bran" and then type in "1 Cup" it knows how many calories, fat content, sugars, etc that I got.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to say just Google it, but... just Google "calorie counter". There are no end of sites that do this. A couple that I've liked include:

[Daily Burn](http://www.dailyburn.com)

[Calorie King](http://www.calorieking.com)

These sites all have most common foods, macronutrient breakdowns, and typically allow users to enter custom foods.

Also, if you want to be a little more hands-on, the USDA publishes a [free nutrient database](http://www.nal.usda.gov/fnic/foodcomp/Data/SR17/dnload/sr17dnld.html).

Comment: Yeah, I should have added that I did Google it, but I didn't want to have to sign up for every single one to find what I wanted, so, that's why I wanted to get some recommendations. I appreciate your response. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan of www.fitday.com.

It has lots of foods in it already where you can set the portion.
You can also enter custom foods right from the nutrition label of whatever you want.

My favorite part of fitday is the pie chart that shows the percentage of calories from fat, carbs, and protein.  That's why I use fitday to write diets for competitors...love the pie chart.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [NutritionData](http://nutritiondata.self.com/).

I would also suggest [MyPyramid](http://www.mypyramid.gov/mypyramid/index.aspx). This site doesn't give the nutrition content of foods, but it can give you a better idea of how many servings of each of the food groups you should be getting. You may find it beneficial for tracking purposes.

Answer (score 1):

For iPhone and Web I used to use [Lose It!](http://www.loseit.com/)  It's one of the best apps and websites out there.

I stopped using it when I went to Android and now use [MyFitnessPal](http://www.myfitnesspal.com) which is also available for the web.

Both of these allow you to create recipes, track foods, calories (fats, carbohydrates and protein) as well as exercises that you do.  If you buy a chocolate bar track it right away and see where you are in your calorie allotment for the day.